# "The bundle currently has sqlite3 locked" when running Passenger server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, sqlite, bundler, passenger

I just added the sqlite gem to our gemfile solely for the purpose of Travis CI testing but now my build on my ubuntu VMBox is broken.

We are using Passenger 4.0.10, Ubuntu 12.04, Rails 4.0 and Ruby 1.9.3. I am using a cron script to pull from git and `touch` the `restart.txt` file to restart the server but the latest build showed the following in the browser:

```
You have requested:
  sqlite3 >= 0

The bundle currently has sqlite3 locked at 1.3.7.
Try running `bundle update sqlite3` (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

When I do execute `bundle update sqlite3` I then get the message:

```
Cannot checkout session. An error occured while starting up the preloader.
Error page:
Could not find colorize-0.5.8 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

(As far as I can tell, this is coming from my Coveralls gem).

I then try to resolve the issue by removing the gem, deleting the `Gemfile.lock` file, and reinstalling the gem. This solves the issue for this gem but the same issue reappears on my next build for another gem. After I perform the same task on each gem, eventually I am confronted with the `The bundle currently has sqlite3 locked at 1.3.7` error once again.

The build works perfectly fine on my Windows 8 machine and seems to run fine on Travis, the problem seems to only be on Ubuntu.

**EDIT**
The problem seems to only occur when running the server using Passenger, executing `rails server` works fine. However, I need passenger (unless there is another solution) to keep auto deployment working.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving the issue by first executing `sudo bundle update sqlite3`. I would then get the message: `Could not find colorize-0.5.8 in any of the sources`.

To solve this I executed: `bundle --deployment`.

After this I ended up with the error message: `Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add`gem 'mysql2'`to your Gemfile.` which was a strange error to get because I do have mysql2 in my gem file.

To solve this issue I removed the `Gemfile.lock` file, executed `bundle --no-deployment` then executed `bundle --deployment`.

After all that, passenger finally works.